# Перевод строки в символьный массив Java

Tags: java, строки, char

Здравствуйте, возможно ли выполнить подобное? Как перевести символьный массив в строку я знаю, а как наоборот?

```
char ich[] = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' };
String str;
str = in.next();
len = str.length();
System.out.println("Length your message");
System.out.println(len);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    ich[i] = str[i];
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_tochararray.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Методы класса [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

1. [toCharArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray())

   ```java
    /**
    * Converts this string to a new character array.
    *
    * @return  a newly allocated character array whose length is the length
    *          of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain
    *          the character sequence represented by this string.
    */
   public char[] toCharArray() {
       // Cannot use Arrays.copyOf because of class initialization order issues
       char result[] = new char[value.length];
       System.arraycopy(value, 0, result, 0, value.length);
       return result;
   }
   ```

   **Пример:** `"SomeText".toCharArray();` - строка в символьный массив.
2. [valueOf(char data[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char%5B%5D))

   ```java
    /**
    * Returns the string representation of the {@code char} array
    * argument. The contents of the character array are copied; subsequent
    * modification of the character array does not affect the returned
    * string.
    *
    * @param   data     the character array.
    * @return  a {@code String} that contains the characters of the
    *          character array.
    */
   public static String valueOf(char data[]) {
       return new String(data);
   }
   ```

   **Пример:** `String.valueOf(charArr);` - символьный массив в строку.

Comment: Можно ещё `new String(charArr)`

Comment: String str;
System.out.println("Message");
str = in.next();
len = str.length();
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
ich[i] = str.toCharArray();
Выдает ошибку, типа запрашивается char, а получает char[]